# Select last inserted rows with $mysqli->insert_id

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Let's say I have a table

**test**

> id (int) | foo varchar(255)

if i do:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO test (foo) VALUES (?),(?);";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param('ss','foo','bar');
$stmt->execute();

$last = $mysqli->insert_id;

$query_ir = "SELECT * FROM test WHERE id<=? ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0,2";
$stmt_ir = $mysqli->prepare($query_ir);
$stmt_ir->bind_param('i',$last);
$stmt_ir->execute();
```

Is it sure i Will i get the 2 records inserted by the 1st query or there is (even a minimal) chance than another query add a row in between the 2 inserts?

Comment: This is just a snippet, connection works,  it is encapsulated in a try-catch block and i will fetch the results afterward. If you think something is missing to fully understand the question please ask.

Comment: You will oony get the last of your inserted rows.

Comment: $query = "INSERT INTO test (foo) VALUES (?),(?);"; in this statement syntax is wrong right?

Comment: try using transaction so that you can "insert->select" with more precision

Comment: you need to read this [pdo insert](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: @Saty is still also true for mysqli? (not PDO) Because *Example 2* would be the appropriate answer to achieve what i want.